# Send a different types messages in message queue linux c

Tags: c, linux, message-queue

I have a code like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/msg.h>

#define MAXLINE 1024

struct my_msgbuf {
        long mtype;
        char mtext[MAXLINE];
};
int main(void)
{
    struct my_msgbuf buf;
    int msqid;
    key_t key;

    if ((key = ftok("client.c", 'B')) == -1) {
        perror("ftok");
        exit(1);
    }

    if ((msqid = msgget(key, 0644 | IPC_CREAT)) == -1) {
        perror("msgget");
        exit(1);
    }

    printf("Write a text:\n");

    buf.mtype = 1; 
    while( fgets(buf.mtext, MAXLINE, stdin) != NULL ) {
        if (msgsnd(msqid, (struct msgbuf *)&buf, sizeof(buf), 0) == -1)
            perror("msgsnd");
    }

    if (msgctl(msqid, IPC_RMID, NULL) == -1) {
        perror("msgctl");
        exit(1);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This code send a message using ipc messages queue in linux (c), but it send messages with type which is equal '1'. I have to send messages but every message have to has different type. I removed "while" and leave only fgets. Fgets without "while" work untill will be new line or you reach MAXLINE. It doesn't work. I wanna reach effect like:

Write a type:
1 (me)
Write a text:
first message(me)
Write a type:
2 (me)
Write a text:
second message(me)
....

After compiled and run the program I reach:

Write a type:
1 (me)
Write a text:
Write a type:
2 (me)
Write a text:
Write a type:
....

It's my code after modifications. What's wrong with it?

````
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/msg.h>

#define MAXLINE 1024

struct my_msgbuf {
        long mtype;
        char mtext[MAXLINE];
};

int main(void)
{
    struct my_msgbuf buf;

    int msqid;
    key_t key;

    if ((key = ftok("client.c", 'B')) == -1) {
        perror("ftok");
        exit(1);
    }

    if ((msqid = msgget(key, 0644 | IPC_CREAT)) == -1) {
        perror("msgget");
        exit(1);
    }
while(1){
        printf("Write a type:\n");
        scanf("%ld", &buf.mtype);
        printf("Write a text:\n");
        fgets(buf.mtext, MAXLINE, stdin);

        if (msgsnd(msqid, (struct msgbuf *)&buf, sizeof(buf), 0) == -1){
            perror("msgsnd");
        }
}

    if (msgctl(msqid, IPC_RMID, NULL) == -1) {
        perror("msgctl");
        exit(1);
    }

    return 0;
}```
````